# Dbpedia spotlight API limits

Tags: spotlight-dbpedia

Are there any limits using the dbpedia-spotlight APIs ?

I found the endpoint documented here https://www.dbpedia-spotlight.org/api but the page does not speak about any limits such as rete-limits and about the endpoint availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to availability, you can check it out at [status.dbpedia-spotlight.org](https://status.dbpedia-spotlight.org/). The API is totally open without any rate-limit, but please try to don't overload our demo server. If you need batch processing, you can install it locally using our [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/u/dbpedia)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that API has several limits. I could not find any documentation about this, but in my experience I discovered:

1. Your requests for API can have until 930 words. (I recommend 900 or less)
2. I did not use for many requests. I guess which restrictions are for 19 or less requests.

I have no problem with limits and I'm grateful for service, but it could useful that is clearly in documentation at web page.

Comment: Very hard to find useful info, thanks . Did you consider raising an Issue on a github or similar community tool?